# Detecting vertical planes in ARCore

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I was wondering if someone was managed to identify vertical planes ahead of the device in realtime using the ARCore SDK.

I was managed to achieve decent result by defining a wall using a line equation:

```
z = Multiplier * x + Constant (For every y)
```

by "for every y" comment I meant that I ignore the y axis(looking at the wall from above as in 2d mapping of a room) in order to calculate a line that defines the wall.

the Multiplier is the rotation between the points:

```
let angleDeg = Float((360 - angle + 360) % 360) * Float.pi / 180.0;
```

The all computation is:

```
let angle: Int = Int((atan2(pointA.z - pointB.z, pointA.x - pointB.x) * 180) / Float.pi) % 360
     yRotation = Float((360 - angle + 360) % 360) * Float.pi / 180.0

    if pointA.x == pointB.x {
         multiplier = Float.infinity
    } else {
         multiplier = (pointA.z - pointB.z) / (pointA.x - pointB.x)
    }
    constant = pointA.z - multiplier * pointA.x
}
```

Now I trigger that computation while the user is walking around and samples many point cloud's points.

The results are good but not as accurate as the horizontal plane detection of the ARCore.

Comment: Interesting. A couple of the sample videos show objects on vertical walls so I assumed they were natively detected as well.

Comment: @RatherNotsay Thanks you. I'll check them and update the thread as I progress

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Not yet, I was switched to a different project for a few weeks. I'll probably get back to it in 2 weeks. What I can share with is that the iOS implemented it in ARKit with the same approach and it works very well for them.

Comment: @Nativ In order to recognize vertical planes using the ARCore SDK, what development environment were you using (Java/OpenGL, Unity, Unreal, Web)?  I am looking to modify the Android Studio example project (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/getting-started) to recognize walls leveraging the code you posted but am unsure where to put it.  Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @gyochum I'm using Java and also started from the sample project. I suggest you fork this repository and add your own features to it. then you can link your solution here and in the main repository pull request that I opened.

Comment: This has been partially solved with the latest release (ARCore 1.0). Now you can put objects in vertical surfaces (normals are being provided for the detected points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now is part of ARCore, was release on [version 1.2.0](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases) for android

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this issue on official Google AR Core github repo https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/31 . This feature is released in ARCore SDK for unity (v1.2.0) [SDK link](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/releases/tag/v1.2.0) as mentioned in the issue. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Since ARCore 1.2 was released we can use four values of `Config.PlaneFindingMode` enumeration.

Here's how a code looks like:

```
public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode DISABLED
// Plane detection is disabled.

public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode HORIZONTAL
// Detection of only horizontal planes is enabled.

public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode VERTICAL
// Detection of only vertical planes is enabled.

public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode HORIZONTAL_AND_VERTICAL
// Detection of both horizontal and vertical planes is enabled.
```