# About ARCore vertical plan and show

Tags: arcore

I have a question, in a recent study Google ARCore, I want to realize detection vertical plane, and be like a horizontal plane, can also renders a plane, I think there are vertical detection ARCore, but how to display them out and use?

Comment: More information available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977545/detecting-vertical-planes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment in the preview version of ARCore, there's only horizontal plane detection in ARCore.

Comment: I can see that the ARCore can detect the Point Cloud either horizontally or vertically, so why can't the vertical plane be made?

Comment: @GameTang ask Google ;)

Answer (score 2):

when I attended the Google Tango workshop a few months ago, at the time arcore wasnt released and arkit was. I asked the engineers the primary difference between the Tango and arkit. Their response was that tango can detect planes in virtually any orientation with their point cloud system which I can confirm does work quite well when I used it during our 2 day workshops at Google. The two are using different technologies to understand the physical world, but I'm guessing with 2 IR depth sensors, you can get more depth information to determine more information out of different surfaces than with that of one/two camera solutions using optical flow to determine foreground/background. Perhaps they are capable of doing it to some degree but with out proper hardware, the results are not stable enough for a public release.

Answer (score 0):

Jane Friedhoff has an interesting workaround to being able to detect vertical planes and wrote about it in [this](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/JaneFriedhoff/20170830/304749/Making_Portal_Painter_inARCore.php) piece:

> In order to orient portals perfectly on surfaces, we would want to put the portal in the right place, and then rotate it so it’s flush with the surface. One way to do this is to get the plane’s normal (the vector perpendicular to its surface), and adjust our portal’s orientation to match. **But complicating this is that ARCore — like many other AR SDKs — only supports flat plane detection, ie floors and tabletops. Vertical features, such as walls, are treated as part of the point cloud, not detected as planes. As such, they do not have real normal values. So how can we work around this?**
>
> While watching folks play around with Portal Painter, I noticed that when they drew on walls, they typically drew on them head-on — not from an angle. **This meant that most of the time, we could assume that the correct orientation of a vertical portal was simply facing the camera.** We could get a surprisingly good hit rate by combining plane normals for the horizontal portals, and “facing the camera” for the vertical ones.

This workaround might work well only for an application like her's but provides a interesting quick way to estimate pose of objects on a vertical plane.

Comment: As you said, this is a very interesting method, and only for specific occasions.
I don't think it suits me, but thank you for your reply. Maybe other ways of doing it indirectly, it takes some time to think about it，Thank you