# ARCore – Detecting Walls

Tags: android, augmented-reality, object-detection, arcore

I was looking at Android's new ARCore library. It has a method to detect horizontal surfaces but none to detect vertical surfaces or walls.

I was actually trying to make the sample app detect walls, but I am having lots of problems.

Is there a way natively or non-natively detect vertical surfaces in ARCore?

Comment: Nothing I have seen seems to be able to do vertical planes ATM

Comment: Are you detecting anything for `NON_HORIZONTAL` plane type: https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Plane.Type

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977545/detecting-vertical-planes

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**

The newest version of ARCore now [also has](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Config.PlaneFindingMode)

```
public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode HORIZONTAL
// Detection of only horizontal planes is enabled.

public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode HORIZONTAL_AND_VERTICAL
// Detection of both horizontal and vertical planes is enabled.
```

**OLD ANSWER**

There is currently [no native way](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Config.PlaneFindingMode):

```
public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode DISABLED
// Plane detection is disabled.

public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode HORIZONTAL
// Detection of only horizontal planes is enabled.
```

A non-native way is sketched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977545/detecting-vertical-planes):
Access the point cloud data and compute horizontal planes yourself. But to make it really work you would have to implement clustering (telling multiple planes apart instead of computing one global plane) and proper outlier rejection (maybe using [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus)).

Personally I think (hope) that the next ARCore update will include vertical planes because I cannot see a mathematical reason for not supporting this.

Comment: I think ARCore now does support this - i.e your hope has been granted. Your link now actually shows this. It might be worth updating as this is still a top hit for search on this question.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the hellosceneform sample and converting it to detect vertical and horizontal planes:

https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hellosceneform

Create a new Fragment subclassing ArFragment and override the getSessionConfiguration method:

```
public class CustomArFrag extends ArFragment {
@Override
protected Config getSessionConfiguration(Session session) {
    Config config = super.getSessionConfiguration(session);
    config.setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.HORIZONTAL_AND_VERTICAL);
    return config;
}
}
```

Change the activity_ux.xml layout to point to it:

```
  <fragment 
    android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.hellosceneform.CustomArFrag"
  .../>
```

Be aware that vertical surfaces won't always be detected. It doesn't seem to like large white walls. It managed to detect the front of my fridge though and I stuck an Android to it like a magnet!

Answer (score 1):

ARCore 1.2 brought for AR developers three new features: `Vertical Plane Detection`, `Cloud Anchors` and `Augmented Images`.

The first feature in a list added two additional Enum values to `Config.PlaneFindingMode`:

```
public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode HORIZONTAL_AND_VERTICAL

public static final Config.PlaneFindingMode VERTICAL
```

Let's see how it looks like using Kotlin:

```
class CustomArFragment: ArFragment () {

    override fun getSessionConfiguration(session: Session?): Config {
        val configuration = super.getSessionConfiguration(session)
        configuration.planeFindingMode = Config.PlaneFindingMode.VERTICAL 
        return configuration
    }
}
```